# How to make a float2 Class in Python

Tags: python, class, math, numbers

I recently wanted to program ray marching in python using ursina engine. to do that i need a special class called ***float2***.
in unity engine you can program ***float2*** normally and give it into your paramater arguments, but in python there is no such class as ***float2***, i tried doing some easy ways to make it but i have problem when i want to store variables.

basically i have a float2 class:

```py
class float2:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x,
        self.y = y
```

it just stores x and y.

then i have some functions where i use the class:

```py
def length(v: float2):
    return float(sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y))

def signedDstToCircle(p: float2, centre: float2, radius: float):
    return length(centre-p) - radius
```

this works great but i hit a roadblock.
i need to asign one variable a from a function:

```py
def signedDstToBox(p: float2, centre: float2, size: float2):
    offset = float2(abs(p-centre) - size)

    # dst from point outside the box to edge (0 if inside the box)
    unsignedDst = length(max(offset, 0))

    # -dst from point inside the box to edge (0 if outside the box)
    dstInsideBox = max(min(offset, 0))
    
    return unsignedDst + dstInsideBox
```

if i try to run the program now with all it gives me an error:

```py
    offset = float2(abs(p-centre) - size)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float2' and 'float2'
```

i think it gives me error because it not a number, so it cant do math operations and also i think when i will fix this issue there will be another problem with storing the variable.

if anyone know how to make this possible so i can math operations and also being able to store variable by just doing `offset = float2(abs(p-centre)-size)` so it will be stored and i can acces it by doing `offset.x` and `offset.y`

thanks in advance, galfar(SpringPeace)

Comment: In the line `offset = float2(abs(p-centre) - size)` errors are: 1) subtraction operator not defined, and 2) float2 constructor takes two arguments but only one given.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't define functions length & signedDstToCircle as class methods?

Comment: Hey, the class float2 is something like float but with two variables. I want it to be exactly like this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mathematics@0.0/api/Unity.Mathematics.float2.html

Comment: Also I didn't define it in class because the class is different thing from the actual code